# I am trying to send exceptions also but it is giving me syntax error

Tags: python, django

Errors:

```
File "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/carrier-circle/backend/details/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
from .views import *
File "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/carrier-circle/backend/details/views.py", line 298
return {"code":402,"error":except}
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Codes:

```
   try:
        api = Details.get_important_links(
         "OdishaGovtJobs",
         "OdishaGovtJobDetails",
         "state-govt-jobs/odisha-govt-jobs"
         )
        return JsonResponse(api,safe=False)
    except:
        return {"code":402,"error":except}
```

I am trying to send exceptions along with status code but it is giving me syntax error

Comment: for first error add `from .views import #model_name` not *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are inside a function

can you try this? This worked for me

```
def my_def():
    try:
        api = Details.get_important_links(
            "OdishaGovtJobs",
            "OdishaGovtJobDetails",
            "state-govt-jobs/odisha-govt-jobs"
        )
        print ('Im a print in the try')
        return JsonResponse(api,safe=False)

    except Exception  as e :
        print ('Im in the except' )
        return {"code":402,"error":e}


print (my_def())
```

Comment: Yes bro it is working but not giving proper error with line number. giving in one line only 
like this:  name 'OdishaGovtJobDtails' is not defined